# ServerSocket.py error

Tags: python, sockets, networking, odoo, serversocket

I am launching my webpage created using Odoo and signing in using my Odoo username and password on chrome and then in parallel on Mozilla. At this time if I refresh my page opened on chrome, I get the following error and it logs out of Odoo and prompts me to sign in again on chrome.

```
2015-09-02 11:00:11,345 6760 ERROR Basetis2 openerp.service.server: Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53019)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 593, in process_request_thread
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 334, in finish_request
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 651, in __init__
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 710, in finish
  File "socket.pyc", line 279, in close
  File "socket.pyc", line 303, in flush
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

However, my connection on Mozilla is still active and can keep using it without requiring to sign in again, until I sign in on chrome odoo again when it logs out of mozilla.

[Here is the source code for SocketServer.py](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3317).

I read somewhere that, this problem occurs when you try to send data on a socket which has been closed for some reason. My understanding is that maybe when I am logging in via chrome and then via mozilla, it is instantly closing the socket used by chrome. The thing is I'm not sure if multi-socket implementation is being used here and I don't know how can I check it either. But this is for sure that only one port is being used.

If this is the case, then how to solve it exactly?

If this is not the case, then what's happening and how can I solve it? Can creating multiple-socket on a single port solve it?

Any idea/suggestion would be helpful! Thanks!